# Ruby, before_action confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In ruby, I'm trying to prevent users from adding someone as a friend if either one of them has the other on their ignore list. In the friendships controller, I'm trying to define

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
before_action :ignored_user,    only: :create
```

And

```
def ignored_user
  if current_user.foes.include?(@user)
    flash[:notice] = "Unable to send friend request."
    redirect_to :back 
  end
end
```

In this context, current_user is the user who is logged in, @user is the user whose profile they're viewing, and foes means "either someone they're choosing to ignore, or someone who's ignoring them." All of that seems to work except the "if current_user blah blah" line. If I replace it with "if current_user.admin?" then it works exactly as you'd expect. If that user is an admin, they can't send anyone friend requests. If I replace it with "if current_user.id == 2", it also works as you'd expect. I've tried replacing the faulty line with many, many variations of the above code, including things like:

```
if Disagreement.where(foe_id: [@user, params[:id]], user_id: [current_user, params[:id]]).first
```

which works elsewhere, just not in the friendships controller.

As for error messages: there are none. My attempts always either end with the friend being added when they shouldn't be, or all friend requests being blocked, including friend requests to users who **aren't** ignored. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where have you assigned a value to `@user`? My guess is that `@user` is `nil`, and `current_user.foes.include?(nil)` is always `false`. To troubleshoot these sort of things, you can add `puts "@user is: #{@user}"` and check the server output in the console to see what is going on.

Comment: Better yet, tell us the value of `current_user`, `current_user.foes` and `@user`. TIP: Instead of `if foo.bar.first` do `if foo.bar.exists?` Instead of instantiating `Disagreement` in this case, it will return true or false.

Comment: Whoops, atuser (stackoverflow isn't letting me post this reply unless I write "atuser") is defined in the users_controller, under the Show action (and a few others). You were right! After adding that, the console output "atuser is: ". I've tried substituting atuser with "User.find(params[:id])", but this error is returned: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FriendshipsController#create
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{name} with '#{primary_key}'=#{id}"
On line 37, which is the "if current_user etc." line.

Comment: @Leito, here's the console output of all the things you mentioned: http://i.imgur.com/PjJ3sR3.png And thanks for the tip! You're right; that does sound better.

Comment: After trying a few things and googling to search for ways other people have tried this: can you think of a way to reference @user in a friendships controller?

Answer (score 0):

A much smarter person than myself gave me the solution. I completely removed the "before_action :ignored_user,    only: :create" part, as well as the "def ignored_user" section. All of that has been replaced with this:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:friend_id])
    if current_user.foes.include?(@user)
      flash[:notice] = "Unable to send friend request. You are ignoring this user or vice versa."
      redirect_to :back
      puts "@user is: #{@user}" #This line only existed for the sake of figuring out the problem
      puts "@user.id is: #{@user.id}" #Same
      puts "current_user.foes are: #{current_user.foes}" #Same
    else
      @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(friend_id: params[:friend_id])
      if @friendship.save
        flash[:notice] = "Friend request sent!"
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem was that the friendships controller couldn't recognize @user in any of the ways it's normally defined, due to the params[:id] part. Because that's rewritten for use in the friendships controller, the controller assumes that by "id," you mean the id of some friendship, not a user's id. The person who gave me the solution realized that you could just replace ":id" with ":friend_id" since, in the context of this action, those two IDs will always be synonymous, since you'll always be adding people from their own profile page. So I never figured out how to **directly** reference a user's ID from within a different controller, but I've learned the next best thing.